# SwiperJS keeps adding margin right to each slide

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, swiper.js

I'm having a Swiper carousel that keeps adding unnecessary margin right (5px) to each slide like this:

[image]

I tried

```css
.swiper-slide {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

but then the cards do not fit into one frame anymore

[image]

The following works temporarily but as soon as I refresh the page the problem re-emerges.

```js
<Swiper
    slidesPerView={1}
    spaceBetween={0} // gets overwritten by SwiperJS?
>
...
</Swiper>
```

I have run out of ideas on how to fix this, would appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Swiper has several configuration options that can affect the carousel's layout. Look for options related to spacing, margins, or padding. For example, the `spaceBetween` option controls the space between slides, and the slidesPerView option determines how many slides are visible at once. Experiment with different values for these options to see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `media queries` and `flex-basis` in percentage, combined with `margin-right: 0px !important;`

```css
.carousel {
    & .swiper-slide {
        margin-right: 0px !important;
        flex-basis: 20%;
    }

    // fix for box-shadow being cut off
    & .swiper-slide:hover {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .carousel {
    & .swiper-slide {
      flex-basis: 25%;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .carousel {
    & .swiper-slide {
      flex-basis: 33.33%;
    }
  }
}

// media queries for other screen widths here
```